# Rubber like bouncy button with UIKit dynamics

Tags: ios, iphone, user-interface, uikit-dynamics

I would like to create a rubber-like button in my iOS app: when the user taps the button it would shrink its frame and when the user releases the tap it would grow, expand a bit and then turn back to its original size with a bouncing effect just like if it was made from rubber. I saw this kind of button in some other apps and I am pretty sure that they used iOS 7 UIKit dynamics to implement this effect. I checked out the different behaviours of UIKit dynamics but none of them seems to be useful as none of them changes the size of the frame. I was wondering if there any hint out there on how to implement this behaviour?

Comment: you are right..
I have given one up-vote..

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is probably not `UIKitDynamics` but just an animation.

`UIKitDynamics` is used for moving things around the screen and applying physics to collisions etc...

What you could use is the new animation method...

```
- (void)animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                      delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay
     usingSpringWithDamping:(CGFloat)dampingRatio
      initialSpringVelocity:(CGFloat)velocity
                    options:(UIViewAnimationOptions)options
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion;
```

This will animate a change but apply a spring like effect to the animation curve.

If you change the frame of the button inside the animations block it will "spring" the new frame and look rubbery.

You can read more about it here... http://www.oliverfoggin.com/animate-with-springs/

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this method, with the help of it I could easily implement the button I wanted (see my own answer)

Answer (score 0):

As Fogmeister answered, animation with spring damping is your friend. If you want to target older versions of iOS, you can write animation code on these lines:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    // increase to 1.1 of the final size
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // reduce to final size in new animation block
}
```

While this is obviously not as flexible as the spring mechanics in iOS 7, visually, it looks quite similar.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fogmeister pointed out the simplest way is to animate the scale of the button with the new `UIView` method "animate...usingSpring..." of iOS 7. I uploaded a sample gists for your reference to  https://gist.github.com/mrtj/9089823

Answer (score 0):

The [UIKit Dynamics Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) sample code includes a demo of what you are trying to achieve. More explicitly, see [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/DynamicsCatalog/Listings/DynamicsCatalog_APLCustomDynamicItemViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013414-DynamicsCatalog_APLCustomDynamicItemViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_16).

Basically you will need a combination of `UIAttachmentBehavior` and `UIPushBehavior`.